# Inserting nomenclature on a page without page number

Tags: page-numbering, nomenclature

I have followed [this example](http://texblog.org/2012/05/14/list-of-symbols-or-abbreviations-nomenclature/) and read [nomencl package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/nomencl/nomencl.pdf) and I can't find a solution. The problem is, that I want to insert nomenclature after TOC, where page numbers are turned off. That is why I get the following error written in .ilg file after makeindex command:

> -- Illegal page number .

All the entries are rejected, because it can't include nomenclature without value in nompageref. If I include it after the page numbering starts, than everything works as expected. Here is how the line in .nlo file looks like:

```
\nomenclatureentry{aCDI@[{CDI}]\begingroup Contexts and Dependency Injection\nomeqref {0}|nompageref}{}
```

As you can see the `nompageref` is missing value.
Is there a way around to include nomenclature without the need for page number?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! May you add a small example of your problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you have turned off the page numbers via

```
\renewcommand{\thepage}{}
```

or similar. Then the entries in `.nlo` are missing the page number and `makeindex` is not happy with those entries without page number. At least a dummy page number is needed and correct page numbers if option `refpage` of package `nomencl` is used. Therefore it is better to turn off the page numbers via the page style instead of turning off redefining `\thepage`:
`\pagestyle{empty}`, `\thispagestyle{empty}`, … For more details a MWE would make sense.