# Nomenclature generation fails on custom template class

Tags: nomenclature, nomencl

I use [this template class](https://github.com/lfochamon/poliTeX) for my master thesis. It is very helpful and neat. However... I am not able to generate a nomenclature on it. I contacted the template's author but is very busy at the moment. :-((

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}

some text
    
    \nomenclature{\(c\)}{Speed of light in a vacuum}
    \nomenclature{\(h\)}{Planck constant}
    \printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

You may reproduce substituting `\documentclass{article}` by `\documentclass{politex}`.

Comment: Please copy the code of the minimal example to this question, to make it self-contained.

Comment: I added the minimal example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class redefines the macro `\thepage` to be empty for the pretextual part. The `nomencl` package stores the page numbers in the `.nlo` file, even though the page number is not printed by default in the nomenclature list, to be processed by `makeindex`. Because the page number is empty when using the `politex` class, `makeindex` issues an error in the .`ilg` file (the index log):

```
!! Input index error (file = yourfile.nlo, line = 1):
   -- Illegal page number .
```

A workaround is to re-redefine `\thepage` to a dummy value, see [Inserting nomenclature on a page without page number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71349/inserting-nomenclature-on-a-page-without-page-number). This does not actually print a page number since the class uses `\pagestyle{empty}` for the pre-textual part.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{politex}

\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}

some text
    \renewcommand{\thepage}{1}
    \nomenclature{\(c\)}{Speed of light in a vacuum}
    \nomenclature{\(h\)}{Planck constant}
    \printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

Comment: You have my thanks. :-)

Comment: Where can I find more about each compilation output information?

Comment: @BrunoPeixoto the way of getting information depends on how you compile. I always compile manually from the terminal, so for your document I first typed `pdflatex yourfile.tex`, then I typed `makeindex yourfile.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o yourfile.nls`. The terminal output showed me some error messages and the names of the relevant log files. Then I opened those log files in a text editor to see the full error. However, if you compile from a GUI editor like TeXStudio, or online via Overleaf, or using a build tool like `latexmk`, then the log information is not always so easy to find as in the [...]

Comment: [...] terminal. Sometimes the extra files such as `.ilg` may even be deleted automatically after the compile process so you can't find the information at all. Usually the information is presented somewhere in the editor interface, but where, what and how exactly depends on which editor it is. For a general list of all the different files that are produced by LaTeX and various packages see https://github.com/wspr/latex-auxfiles/blob/master/auxfiles.tex, that could help you locate the relevant log files to check for errors and warning.

Comment: Very informative. Your comment should be framed on tex.stackexchange hall of fame.